# calculate angle of Delaunay triangles with horizon

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry

i have a set of points in 3 dimensional space and i've used Delaunay triangulation to create a surface over them like this

[image]

Having the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of every vertex, can i somehow calculate the angle that each triangle makes with the horizon ($xy$ plane)? maybe using cross product ?

Comment: Yes, if a triangle has vertices $V_i(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ compute the cross product  $N=\vec{V_1V_2} \times \vec{V_1V_3}$ giving the normal to your triangle, Take $N'=N/\|N\|$ in order to have a unit normal, compute the dot product of $N'$ with the unit vector (0,0,1) of the $z$ axis : taking its absolute value, you get the cosine of the angle of the normal to the triangle with the $z$ axis.

Comment: Usually, if a software like Matlab gives you a Delaunay triangulation, it gives you also access to normals.

Comment: @JeanMarie why should i compute the dot produt with (0,0,1)? why not the unit vector of x? I'm using python.

Comment: Because taking the dot product with a unit vector is equivalent to multiply by a cosine, therefore gives the "length of the projection  on the axis defined by this unit vector".

Comment: I haven't answered conveniently to your question : it is only with the $z$ axis that you measure the horizontality default. From 1 for perfect horizontality till 0 for perfect verticality. Another way of seeing it; if you take the $x$ axis, one can object you : why not the $y$ axis ?